# Is there a way to make a shop in bedrock minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there any way to create a shop where people can buy and sell items in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition? I am trying to make a game, but I cannot figure out how to create a shop.

Comment: Do you know some basic commands? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It would not be possible if it is one shop. In order to do that you need to create many shops. One area for selling, and one area for buying. If it was in one contraption, then the shop would be super big for multiple things. Plus you would need a lot of materials if your doing in survivor. You should try using commands in order to succeed this task.

Comment: He will be using commands, that's why it's tagged [tag:minecraft-commands]